# Disable ValidatesOnDataErrors if CheckBox is Checked WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I am trying to disable ValidatesOnDataErrors on a TextBox if a certain checkbox is checked. 
I have tried placing a trigger on textbox to enable or disable validation based on the checkbox seems like the trigger gets hit but does not disable validation. I am using **IDataErrorInfo** for validation in the **.cs** code. Here is the code I have tried, this has been a headache so hope you can help.

**.xaml**

```
<TextBox Name="txtFoundERTReading" Height="23" Canvas.Left="125" TextWrapping="Wrap" Canvas.Top="136" Width="120">
    <TextBox.Style>                                
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">                                    
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbFoundERTReading, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Found.ERTReading, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbFoundERTReading, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="TextBox.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Found.ERTReading, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=False, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />                                            
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of changing the ValidatesOnDataErrors property at run time, the best approach is to have a boolean property in viewmodel and do validation only if it is true. The boolean property can bound to IsChecked property of a Checkbox.

```
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (CanValidate)
            {
                if (columnName == "Name")
                {
                    if (!ValidateName())
                    {
                        return "Error";
                    }
                }
            }

            return "";
        }
    }

    private bool canValidate;

    public bool CanValidate
    {
        get { return canValidate; }
        set { canValidate = value; RaisePropertyChanged("CanValidate"); RaisePropertyChanged("Name");}
    }

    private bool ValidateName()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The XAML looks like below,

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Margin="5" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <CheckBox Margin="5" Content="Can validate" IsChecked="{Binding CanValidate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks much for a quick reply. I have 5 textboxes and each of them have a corresponding checkbox. I would hate to have 5 bool properties to check for each textbox? Is there a way to avoid that? The 5 textboxes are required unless you click on a checkbox that says "Unable to Read" that is when I would like to disable validation and remove the red color from textbox border (Caused by ValidatesOnDataError).

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"
```